# Get query string parameters url values with jQuery / Javascript (querystring)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-plugins, query-string

Anyone know of a good way to write a jQuery extension to handle query string parameters? I basically want to extend the jQuery magic `($)` function so I can do something like this:

```
$('?search').val();
```

Which would give me the value "test" in the following URL: `http://www.example.com/index.php?search=test`.

I've seen a lot of functions that can do this in jQuery and Javascript, but I actually want to extend jQuery to work exactly as it is shown above. I'm not looking for a jQuery plugin, I'm looking for an extension to the jQuery method.

Comment: Asked and answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @NicoWesterdale - I went through that link, but didn't see any answers that solve this particular question. He said he wants exactly as above.

Comment: I don't think you can do this, a string passed in gets parsed by sizzler, then resolved to an array of DOM objects. You can extend the matcher to provide custom filters, but you can't have a jquery object based on a string.

Comment: Isn't `$` overloaded enough?

Comment: @mrtsherman Look at the getParameterByName() function in the link I provided. No you can't do it from directly within a $ prompt, but that's not what jQuery selectors are for. He's just selecting part of a URL string, not trying to access part of the DOM which is what $() does. It's a totally different thing. If you really wanted to use jQuery you could write a plugin that used this syntax: $.getParameterByName(param), there's an example further down on that page I linked to that does exactly that. Kinda pointless though.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

After years of ugly string parsing, there's a better way: **URLSearchParams** Let's have a look at how we can use this new API to get values from the location!

```
//Assuming URL has "?post=1234&action=edit"

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(urlParams.has('post')); // true
console.log(urlParams.get('action')); // "edit"
console.log(urlParams.getAll('action')); // ["edit"]
console.log(urlParams.toString()); // "?post=1234&action=edit"
console.log(urlParams.append('active', '1')); // "?

post=1234&action=edit&active=1"
```

## **UPDATE (03/21/24) : All Major Browsers Now Supported**

URLSearchParams [is now supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#browser_compatibility) by all major browsers

## <s>**UPDATE : IE is not supported**</s>

use this function from [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152400/2172174) instead of **URLSearchParams**

```
$.urlParam = function (name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                      .exec(window.location.search);

    return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}

console.log($.urlParam('action')); //edit
```

Comment: is URLSearchParams supported by all browsers?

Comment: Oops! ohh man, IE is not supported !!  I have just tested on it. While Chrome, FF, Safari has no issue.

Comment: @divine - There is a polyfill for URLSearchParams here: https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params

Comment: If you add a polyfill for unsupported browsers this URLSearchParams solution works well. https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params

Comment: wont work with say `https://mytest.com/bippo/#/?utm_source=teeest` or  `https://mytest.com/bippo/#/url/?utm_source=teeest`

Comment: The solution is not complete, il should call `decodeURIComponent`, and replace `+` with space... see previous solution

Comment: Another polyfill is https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill

Answer (score 114):

Why extend jQuery?  What would be the benefit of extending jQuery vs just having a global function?

```
function qs(key) {
    key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx meta chars
    var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]"+key+"=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/sgxcL/

An alternative approach would be to parse the entire query string and store the values in an object for later use.  This approach doesn't require a regular expression and extends the `window.location` object (but, could just as easily use a global variable):

```
location.queryString = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function (pair) {
    if (pair === "") return;
    var parts = pair.split("=");
    location.queryString[parts[0]] = parts[1] &&
        decodeURIComponent(parts[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/YnCeu/

This version also makes use of `Array.forEach()`, which is unavailable natively in IE7 and IE8.  It can be added by using [the implementation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility), or you can use jQuery's [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead.

Comment: It's not common but it is valid to use semi-colons instead of ampersands in the query parameters.

Comment: @Muhd - It's "valid" to use any delimiter you like in a querystring as long as your code understands it.  But, when a form is submitted, the form fields are submitted as `name=value` pairs, separated by `&`.  If your code is using a custom querystring format, obviously, you'll need to write a custom querystring parser wherever the querystring is consumed, whether on the server or the client.

Comment: The W3C recommendation is to use semi-colon delimiters, see http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2

Comment: @nick - Interesting. But their suggestion for HTTP servers to treat semi-colons as ampersands only serves to make HTML prettier when using a link to mimic a form submission. It is just a suggestion and is non-standard. A standard form `GET` submission is encoded as [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), with values separated by `&`. My code handles that standard. Custom url structures such as the one you linked will need a custom parser server-side and client-side. Regardless, adding such capability to my code above would be trivial.

Comment: @gilly indeed - if you want portable code you need to support both

Comment: Add "i" to the RegExp() so the key can be case insensitive: new RegExp("[?&]"+key+"=([^&]+)(&|$)", "i"));

Comment: This properly handled where a query param contained a plus (+) sign, while other examples did not.

Comment: dont understand the jsfiddle. Will this work for example with:  `https://mytest.com/bippo/#/url/?utm_source=teeest`

Comment: @Toskan - You can adapt it to work.  I assume you want to treat the `?utm_source=teeest` portion as the querystring.  Since that portion in your URL comes after the `#`, it's not part of the traditional querystring, and thus not available in `location.search`, which both of my examples rely on.  You can modify my `qs` function to use `location.hash` instead of `location.search` and it will work.

Answer (score 96):

<strike>JQuery [jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parse) plugin do the same job, for example to retrieve the value of **search** query string param, you can use</strike>

```
$.url().param('search');
```

This library is not actively maintained. As suggested by the author of the same plugin, you can use [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js).

Or you can use [js-url](https://github.com/websanova/js-url) instead. Its quite similar to the one below.

So you can access the query param like `$.url('?search')`

Comment: Nice.  And the code is in the public domain so you don't even have to include the comments.

Comment: Good solution but won't work if you happen to be testing via file://

Comment: Whats that have to do  anything with, @kampsj

Comment: Hi @kampsj, testing with `file://` protocol will cause a lot more stuff not to work.  You can create a very quick and easy static HTML server with node.js.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http

Comment: Why we need plugin for very small task?

Comment: Its based on the needs, if you are  pereforming more than just retrieving a field from URL.. So if you dont want to use a plugin, then checkout the answers below, there are lot of alternatives

Comment: This plugin is no longer maintained and the author itself is suggesting to use other plugins instead.

Comment: thanks @JanErikGunnar, Please check the updated answer

Comment: @RameshVel Did you intend for both URI.js and js-url links to point to the same location? Maybe you meant js-url to point [here](https://github.com/websanova/js-url)?

Comment: @M.Babcock yep the link was wrong. fixed now. thank you

Answer (score 95):

Found this gem from our friends over at SitePoint.
https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/.

Using PURE jQuery.  I just used this and it worked. Tweaked it a bit for example sake.

```
//URL is http://www.example.com/mypage?ref=registration&email=bobo@example.com

$.urlParam = function (name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                      .exec(window.location.search);

    return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
}

console.log($.urlParam('ref')); //registration
console.log($.urlParam('email')); //bobo@example.com
```

Use as you will.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I don't think you need the last closing brace tag though.

Comment: Ahh yes, you are correct.  Edited the post. That was left over from some if statement in my code.  Thanks.

Comment: You should use window.location.search instead of .href -- otherwise, good.

Comment: Instead of `results[1] || 0`, you must do if (results) {return results[1]} return 0; bcoz query parameters may not be present at all. And modifying will handle all generic cases.

Comment: The return statement should be `return (results && results[1]) || 0;`

Comment: If the param is not set, it'll return `null`, and cause an error. I modified it to: `return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;` to solve the issue. This way it'll return `false` if the param is not set. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: What do you do if you have something like `https://example.com/?c=Order+ID` ? That plus sign still remains on this function.

Comment: "Using PURE jQuery." This solution doesn't actually use any JQuery. It only extends JQuery with what could just as easily be a stand alone function.

Comment: To get rid of the plus sign and decode use `decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('email').replace(/\+/g," "));`

Comment: wont work with `https://mytest.com/bippo/#/url/?utm_source=teeest`

Comment: $.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}

Answer (score 48):

This isn't my code sample, but I've used it in the past.

```
//First Add this to extend jQuery

    $.extend({
      getUrlVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
      },
      getUrlVar: function(name){
        return $.getUrlVars()[name];
      }
    });

    //Second call with this:
    // Get object of URL parameters
    var allVars = $.getUrlVars();

    // Getting URL var by its name
    var byName = $.getUrlVar('name');
```

Comment: You shouldn't split on '=', it's technically okay to have a second equals sign in the value of any key/value pair. -- Only the first equals sign you encounter (per key/value pair) should be treated as a delimiter. (Also, the equals sign isn't strictly required; it's possible to have a key with no value.)

Comment: Clean solution. Worked perfectly in my case.

Comment: $.extend({
      getUrlVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          var k = hash.shift();
          vars.push(k);
          vars[k] = hash.join("");
        }
        return vars;
      },
      getUrlVar: function(name){
        return $.getUrlVars()[name];
      }
    });

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a little function where you only have to parse the name of the query parameter. So if you have: ?Project=12&Mode=200&date=2013-05-27  and you want the 'Mode' parameter you only have to parse the 'Mode' name into the function:

```
function getParameterByName( name ){
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)", 
  regex = new RegExp( regexS ),
  results = regex.exec( window.location.search );
  if( results == null ){
    return "";
  } else{
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
}

// example caller:
var result =  getParameterByName('Mode');
```

Comment: If your name has no junk, you can drop the first regex and it make more sense to start from location.search

Answer (score 8):

Building on @Rob Neild's answer above, here is a pure JS adaptation that returns a simple object of decoded query string params (no %20's, etc).

```
function parseQueryString () {
  var parsedParameters = {},
    uriParameters = location.search.substr(1).split('&');

  for (var i = 0; i < uriParameters.length; i++) {
    var parameter = uriParameters[i].split('=');
    parsedParameters[parameter[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parameter[1]);
  }

  return parsedParameters;
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen any erroring using this code. What browser are you using? I've tested it against current Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: Yeah sorry I read it wrong. I thought I saw it call a method on something that was returning undefined. So really it's just running once when it doesn't have to. When search is `""`. And you get {"": "undefined"}

Comment: Yeah. That could probably use some refining.

Answer (score 3):

```
function parseQueryString(queryString) {
    if (!queryString) {
        return false;
    }

    let queries = queryString.split("&"), params = {}, temp;

    for (let i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        if (temp[1] !== '') {
            params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

I use this.

Answer (score 2):

Written in Vanilla Javascript

```
     //Get URL
     var loc = window.location.href;
     console.log(loc);
     var index = loc.indexOf("?");
     console.log(loc.substr(index+1));
     var splitted = loc.substr(index+1).split('&');
     console.log(splitted);
     var paramObj = [];
     for(var i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
         var params = splitted[i].split('=');
         var key = params[0];
         var value = params[1];
         var obj = {
             [key] : value
         };
         paramObj.push(obj);
         }
    console.log(paramObj);
    //Loop through paramObj to get all the params in query string.
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getQueryStringValue(uri, key) {        
        var regEx = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");        
        var matches = uri.match(regEx);
        return matches == null ? null : matches[1];
}

function testQueryString(){
   var uri = document.getElementById("uri").value;
   var searchKey = document.getElementById("searchKey").value;
   var result = getQueryStringValue(uri, searchKey);
   document.getElementById("result").value = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="uri" placeholder="Uri"/>
<input type="text" id="searchKey" placeholder="Search Key"/>
<Button onclick="testQueryString()">Run</Button><br/>

<input type="text" id="result" disabled placeholder="Result"/>
```