# How to keep dropdown list value after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <select name="Year" id="Year" value="">
        <option value=""></option>              
    </select> 
</td>
```

**JavaScript to create the list**

```
for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
{
    $('#Year').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}
```

How do i keep the value of the year that is submitted?

Comment: what do you mean by keeping? after submitting you can get the value in php file right?

Comment: yeah it is passed to a php file using GET

Comment: What does the  page url look like after you submit?

Comment: @LShetty https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~b00518407/workspace/projectfile/search.php?searchInput=&srch_author=&Year=1998&srch_publisher=&srch_category=

Comment: @LShetty search.php?searchInput=&srch_author=&Year=1998&srch_publisher=&srch_category=

Comment: So, take the year from the querystring and set it to the select box.

Comment: See my answer below that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, since you have the year in the querystring, grab that and set it to the select box.

```
$('#Year').val(location.search.match(/year=([^&]+)/i)[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way is to pass $_POST['Year'] to a session or a cookie or to insert it into a database table and through PDO or MySQLi commands fetch the specific result anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you'll have access to the values that are posted.  In this case it will be in `$_POST['Year']`, `$_GET['Year']` or `$_REQUEST['Year']`, as `Year` is the name of your `select`.

The issue you have is that the `select` is built by javascript, rather than PHP.  Because of that you need to set it using javascript too.  Therefore you need to get the data from PHP into javascript - does that make sense to you?

OK.

So what you need to do, is generate a call to a javascript function using PHP.  When the browser receives and renders the page it will run the javascript and set the value.

An example might be:

```
$year = $_POST['Year'];
echo( "<script>$('#Year').val('$year')<\script>" );
```

This would depend on how your PHP outputs the pages (I.E. what frameworks you are using, etc)

However, by far the simplest solution would be be actually build the `select` in PHP instead - if that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is submitted to itself via GET, you can [read the value from the querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732379/361684) and set the value on the list:

```
for (var i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
{
    $('#Year').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}
if (/[&?]Year=(\d{4})(&|$)/.test(location.search)) {
    var year = RegExp.$1;
    $('#Year').val(year);
}
```