# Get Query String Param in "Web API redirect (URI)"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api2

```
   [Route("user/Report")]
public IHttpActionResult Report()
{
   string url = "https://localhost:xxxx/User/ReportPage.html?Param1=value";
   System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(url);
   return Redirect(uri);
}
```

i am trying to Get "param1" in ReportPage.html using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get query string parameters with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731778/get-query-string-parameters-with-jquery)

Comment: Sir using Redirect(uri) i can't  get querystring because it will not change the browser url

Comment: Then if it's not there you wont get it, simple. Use something like the ViewBag mechanism to save the parameter.